# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт срабатывал, когда он отображается на экране?

Tags: jquery

У меня есть скрипт, который увеличивает число от 0 до 28. Но мне надо, чтобы он начинал прибавляться, когда пользователь промотает сайт до этого места. Как это сделать? Вот код:

```
let cif = document.querySelector(".year");

animate({elem: cif, to: 28, sec: 5});

function animate({elem, from = 0, to, sec}) {
let tick = (to - from) / (60 * sec);
// 60 - это 60 кадров в секунду, от requestAnimationFrame

loop();
function loop() {
    elem.textContent = Math.round( from += tick );
    
    if( from >= to ) {
    elem.textContent = to;
    return;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся только когда элемент находится в зоне видимости экрана?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140165/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cif = document.querySelector(".year");
let already_there = false; //Проверка на то "были ли мы там"
$(document).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(".year").offset().top+$(".year").height()&&!already_there){ 
      //Проверяем растояние до елемента, запускаем анимацию и меняем статус
      animate({elem: cif, to: 28, sec: 5});
      already_there=true;
  }
})

function animate({elem, from = 0, to, sec}) {
let tick = (to - from) / (60 * sec);
// 60 - это 60 кадров в секунду, от requestAnimationFrame

loop();
function loop() {
    elem.textContent = Math.round( from += tick );
    
    if( from >= to ) {
    elem.textContent = to;
    return;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
}
```